# Channel Videos with https?

Tags: channel-videos

Has anyone used the Channel Videos add-on with https? I have tried rewriting all of the URLs in the add-on with https and also tried rewriting the URLs to just //, without a protocol. Both of those methods still produce insecure content on the site. I would appreciate any feedback the community has to offer. I love this add-on, and I really want to use it on this site.

Comment: Not sure if there is a better way so I leave this as a comment. In the past I have hacked the core code to do this, not sure if there is a native way now.

Comment: How are you embedding the videos? Is it an iframe that is output on the page? I've not used Channel Videos before but [YouTube supports HTTPS](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/02/https-support-for-youtube-embeds.html) so can't you just change that to being HTTPS?

Comment: I am embedding using https, and I am now using YouTube's url for the thumbnails instead Channel Video's img_url_hd tag. This has helped with keeping the green bar when the page loads, but now when I play the video, the green bar disappears.

Comment: Are you testing with Google Chrome? I know Chrome can be particularly fussy about that sort of thing but I'd be curious to see if it's the same across other browsers. Is it an actual warning or just a disappearance of the green bar?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: So it turns out, Channel Videos has https built in. I combed through the add-on, and found the code that checks if you are currently on https.

Comment: Doh! Far too easy. ;)

Comment: Agreed. It would be helpful if they added that tidbit of information to the documentation. I wasn't able to figure this out without combing through the add-on files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Channel Videos has https built in.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your Channel Video tags with [Find and Replace](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/find-and-replace-plus) to swap out the protocol:

```
{exp:replace_plus find='http:' replace='https:'}

    {exp:channel_videos:videos}
        <!-- Template Code -->
    {/exp:channel_videos:videos}

{/exp:replace_plus}
```

As I've not used Channel Videos before and can't see what is actually being output in the template files you may need to tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Taking YouTube as an example, how about adding this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^youtube/(.*)$ http://www.youtube.com/$1 [L]
```

And then prefixing the video link with your domain over HTTPS:

```
<embed src="https://www.yourdomain.com/youtube/v/embed_code" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="560" height="340"></embed>
```

The key is adding `https://www.yourdomain.com/youtube/` to the source URI. Apache will then see this and rewrite them to the regular YouTube URI which may result in removing the security warnings.

Again, having not used Channel Videos specifically I'm not sure how you add the source URI but if you have control of this then give that a go.