# Unable to search for YouTube videos in DevDemon's Channel Videos

Tags: devdemon, channel-videos

I have installed the latest version of Channel Videos 3.2.0A. When I am in the channel entry and try to search for a YouTube video, or manually enter the YouTube URL, I just get a spinning circle. It never completes the search. Vimeo works fine. I don't know if this is related to the latest api changes with YouTube. Are we supposed to be entering an api key? I didn't see anything about it in the documentation.

Thanks

**Additional information: This is an MSM install, and Channel Videos is searching YouTube properly on the other 2 MSM sites. The only thing I can think of that is different about this site is that there is an SSL certificate  of the site where I'm having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried your version on a fresh install (EE 2.10.1) and it's working as expected: Fields populate and I can see previews and all in the backend (I've not built a page yet). The search and capture of data from YT doesn't seem dependant on an API key (I've not used one), so I think it's environmental.

- What EE are you on?
- Which URL are you embedding? The shared one
  (exposed when you click the share button below the video, right?)

Comment: I'm on EE 2.9.2. See the note I added to my original question.  

And yes, I'm using the link from the share button.

Comment: Ah - https with a ssl cert...I've never come across this myself but this might be of some help:

http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/channel-videos-with-https?rq=1

Comment: Adding a rule to my .htaccess file didn't work, so I ended up installing the Antenna plugin, and that's working without a problem with YouTube. I like Channel Videos better, but this will do.